# Extract Google Sheet ID with REGEXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

Although the Google Sheet ID can be referenced in Apps Script with the following `getSheetId()`, I find the need to extract the ID within a Google Sheets cell.

I have extracted the first part of the URL but not the ID. Using:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(F2,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)")
```

Luckily the URLs imported will always have the same format, so no need for a variable regex to handle different forms on the URL

Sheet URL

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZNU46cVFMebj8t-kFXySuZyTTTupCo8EMrHr1exXr6Zg/edit#gid=757856732

**Sheet ID** (always occurs after 5th forward slash and before the last forward slash)

1ZNU46cVFMebj8t-kFXySuZyTTTupCo8EMrHr1exXr6Zg

How can I specifically get the Google Sheet ID from the URL referenced in another cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID is always between the last but one and the last `/` you may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, ".*/(.*)/")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSJbzT/1)

**Details**

- `.*` - 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a backslash (the last but one backslash)
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1 (the value returned by `REGEXEXTRACT` will be this one): 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a backslash (it will be the last backslash in the string).

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, "/"),, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If any body is interested on getting that in PHP here is the code for it

```
$sheetlink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/HERE IS THE GOOGLE SHEET ID/edit#gid=123"    
$sheetlink = preg_split('/(d\/|\/edit)/', $sheetlink);

echo $sheetlink['1'];
```